# Android Button that stays always above the all activities for standby

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to make a Button which will always be on standby like Floating Action button despite whatever context it may be in but shall sustain all above my activities, How could I achieve this please refer me a link or give me an idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet would probably be to make an abstract activity that contains that button and adds it to the layouts of all activity that inherit from it. That way you don't have to duplicate the code in every activity.

Comment: you would have a bunch of different buttons then. Makes it harder to manage the state

Comment: You'd only have 1 button. The abstract activity will contain it and its functionality.

Comment: every activity that inherits from it will create its own instance of the button

Comment: Yes it would, but as only 1 activity is in the foreground at a time I dont see how that would be an issue. Especially if the button will always have the same behavior. Using fragments is definitely a better solution but it seems hes already built the activities.

Comment: Yeah this take quite generous but then i have to implement its action in to the hell lot of activities.

Comment: Suppose activity A has a button. Something happens that alters the state of the button, maybe the color has changed. Then user moves to activity B, which also has that button (but not the same one), the state will be reset because B doesn't know that A modified it

Comment: Yeah, but the OP didn't mention anything about the state of the button needing to be maintained. As I said, fragments would be more elegant solution, but if a requirement for whatever reason is to use activities this solution is definitely workable.

Answer (score 4):

One solution is to create a single activity with the button and then use fragments instead of the current activities.

Comment: But i I've to create several activities as my requirement

Answer (score 2):

```
class ActivityOne extends BaseActivity{
  @Override 
  protected View childView(){
      return getLayoutInflator().inflate(R.layout.activity_one, null);
   }
}

class ActivityTwo extends BaseActivity{
   @Override
   protected View childView(){
      return getLayoutInflator().inflate(R.layout.activity_two, null);
   }
}

public abstract class BaseActivity extends Activity{

   protected abstract View childView();

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(SavedInstanceState savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    RelativeLayout baseLayout;
    ViewStub stub;
    baseLayout = (RelativeLayout)
    this.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.layout_base, null);
    stub = (ViewStub) baseLayout.findViewById(R.id.base_content_stub);

    // Replace viewstub with content.
    baseLayout.removeView(stub);
    baseLayout.addView(childView(), stub.getLayoutParams());

    super.setContentView(baseLayout);
   }
}
```

**layout_base.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout 
 ....
>
 <ViewStub 
  android:layout_width = "match_parent"
  android:layout_height = "match_parent"
  android:id="@+id/base_content_stub"/>

 <Button 
 .... // <---- common to all activities
 />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Doing the same stuff...wait a minute

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to use the same button for every activity. You could use the same layout, but you'd have to create the button anew every time you created a new activity. You might be able to avoid that if you did some fancy stuff with the action bar that is frankly not worth it. I suggest you look at using fragments instead of activities, in which case you can have your layout file for you activity look something like this:

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="coop.nisc.intern2016.ui.MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/button_text" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Then, you can use a `FragmentManager` to put the fragment into the `fragment_container`. The code could look something like this:

```
private void showCustomFragment() {
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    customFragment = new customFragment();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.fragment_container, customFragment, customFragment.TAG)
            .commit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a `BaseActivity` class as a usual activity and a corresponding xml layout file with any layout you want. Add your button inside this layout, and a `FrameLayout` **below** the button. Code your button inside the `onCreate()` of the above activity. Your button's done.

Now, make all your other activities extend the `BaseActivity`, the `super.onCreate()` will take care of the button. Instead of `setContentView()` use:

```
FrameLayout contentFrameLayout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.content_frame); //Remember this is the FrameLayout area within your base activity xml


getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.the_layout_you_want_to_load, contentFrameLayout);
```

'the_layout_you_want_to_load'

is the layout xml of your current activity.