# How to Show Custom View (FAB) On All Screen in Android

Tags: java, android, view

I want to show my custom floating button on all screen in my app without putting it in each activity.

Do we have some Global Activity like put a code once will show the Custom View all screen and hide/remove when app killed

I tried lot of things like Screen Overlay display over all apps
Please check code here - [How to display custom view on all screen in android from my library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71582101/how-to-display-custom-view-on-all-screen-in-android-from-my-library)

Comment: Create a BaseActivity which add a Fab on top of layout and extend it from all your activities, here's how to do it https://stackoverflow.com/a/45637502/4039784

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I've never tried to do it the Java/Kotlin way. But have you considered using Fragments?

You can declare xml layout and code for one Activity with a **FrameLayout** *container* and an *FAB*. The *container* holds all your screens and they switch between each other in the *container*. The *FAB* is on top and therefore will be displayed no matter the screen.

The *Activity* has a reference to any screen that might be displayed in it, so the *FAB* can behave accordingly.

Not sure if this helps. Perhaps if I see some pictures, I could suggest better.

Related Read:
Creating a fragment: [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/create)

Fragment Transactions: [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/transactions)

Comment: I have 15 Screen in my app very screen using a new layout So I can't use fragments. I want a way to show may Custom View (FAB) on Top of every activity

Comment: Help me out here. Have you looked into optimizing the use of 15 fragments with Jetpack Navigator? That might be a better way to approach your problem than having to create an FAB on every activity imho.

Comment: Please check here @Alula48  -  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71582101/how-to-display-custom-view-on-all-screen-in-android-from-my-library